# How to find the minimum shear area of a rectangular thread

Tags: mechanical-engineering, threads

I am trying to find a method of calculating the minimum shear area of the following rectangular thread form. It is a 4.125" square thread, 8 T.P.I., straight, right-hand thread. The thread is loaded in the axial direction, thus I would like to calculate the minimum thread shear strength.

[image: Thread]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area equation of the thread is PI * D * nut length * .060/(.060*.065)
PI = 3.14, D is 4.125-2*.050, nut length not given, probably 1" to 4", .060/(.060*.065) ratio of thread to machined out area

Comment: I assume you mean .060/(.060+.065). This gives A = (3.14)*(4.025 in)*(1.122 in)* .060/(.060+.065) = 6.807 in^2.